# Create dynamic model in Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-modeladmin, django-shell

How to create `Dynamic models` in Django `1.8`?

I have done the following according to the [official site](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels):

```
>>attrs = {
            'name': models.CharField(max_length=32),
            '__module__': 'myapp.models'
          }
>>person = type("ptable", (models.Model,), attrs)

>>def install(model):
      from django.core.management import sql, color
      from django.db import connection
      style = color.no_style()
      cursor = connection.cursor()
      statements, pending = sql.sql_model_create(model, style)
      for sql in statements:
          cursor.execute(sql)

>>install(person)
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "<console>", line 6, in install
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sql_model_create'
```

How to solve it?

Comment: `sql_model_create` method is depricated. There is a `sql_custom` method but as such I wasnt able to find the related docs.

Comment: @TarunBehal:  Oh! Please let me know if you get the related docs for `sql_custom` . Thanks!